# Android default locale change after webview open

Tags: android, webview, locale, multilingual

I am stuck with webview and Locale. in my multilingual app when user change app language from app settings and then user navigate to webview inside app then app locale change to English which is device default language.

Below is my code to change language from setting -

```
private String Locale_English = "en";
private String Locale_RU = "ru";
private void setLanguage(String type){
    Locale locale = new Locale(type);
    Locale.setDefault(locale);
    finish();
}
```

Suppose user selects Russian language and after this user navigates to app dashboard and language changes on all screens, but if user opens a static page from left menu which opens webview in app then device locale changes and on dashboard all labels changes to english.

below is code in my base activity which is parent of dashboardactivity

```
 @Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N){
        mCurrentLocale = getResources().getConfiguration().getLocales().get(0);
    } else{
        //noinspection deprecation
        mCurrentLocale = getResources().getConfiguration().locale;
    }
}

@Override
protected void onRestart() {
    super.onRestart();
    Locale locale = getLocale(this);
    if (!locale.equals(mCurrentLocale)) {
        mCurrentLocale = locale;
        setLocale();
        recreate();
    }
}

private void setLocale() {
    final Resources resources = getResources();
    final Configuration configuration = resources.getConfiguration();
    final Locale locale = getLocale(this);
    if (!configuration.locale.equals(locale)) {
        configuration.setLocale(locale);
        resources.updateConfiguration(configuration, null);
    }
   // Locale locale1 = getLocale(this);;

    Locale locale1= new Locale(getLocaleStr(this));
    Locale.setDefault(locale1);
}

public Locale getLocale(Context context){
    int language = SessionParam.getPrefDataInt(context,"Current_Language");
    String lang = "en";
    switch (language) {
        case 0:
            lang = "en";
            break;
        case 1:
            lang = "ru";
            break;
    }
    return new Locale(lang);
}
```

i debugged the whole flow and issue is after webview loads then user navigates to any screen then language changes to English.

Comment: have you resolve this?